# Offline data -- Should I develop an app in Adobe Air because of a user requirement to have some offline data?

Tags: sql, sqlite, air, offline-mode

I have a client that insists a part of their application will allow for some form entry offline, with a sync of data when the user is back online.

I tried talking them out of it, thinking of some apps I've used in the past (MS CRM comes to mind).

However, I see that Air will write to SQLlite, and I tend to believe that it could be an acceptable solution. They will not have very many users, only about 10, and this would otherwise be proposed as a browser based web app.

Is my proposed solution a good choice, or are there better ways of providing for offline data in web apps (not HTML5 -- need SQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If application should work (partly) offline, how you can do it *without* AIR? This is a good choice, if installation of runtime and app itself is acceptable.

Comment: Installation of runtime and app is totally fine (small group, internal use, but decentralized). Without AIR I was thinking perhaps of a compiled application with SQLlite locally, but hope to not go that route.